# Запуск rsync через subprocess python в windows

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, rsync

Необходимо из Python 2.7 приложения под windows 7 x64 запускать rsync на удаленную машину.

rsync - сборка cwRsync 5.5.0.

Всё отлично работает из консоли:
устанавливаю CWRSYNCHOME= в окружении, указывая на папку с бинарниками и библиотеками cygwin, после чего запускаю командой

```
rsync "/cygdrive/e/test" test1@192.168.1.14:
```

Но когда пытаюсь запустить из под python:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['rsync.exe', '/cygdrive/e/test', 'test1@192.168.1.14:'],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           shell=True,
                           env={'CWRSYNCHOME': './bin'})

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print 'STDOUT:{}\nSTDERR:{}'.format(stdout, stderr)
```

получаю в stderr ошибку

```
rsync: pipe: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(59) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Вывод rsync в stdout с опцией --verbose

```
FILE_STRUCT_LEN=16, EXTRA_LEN=4
cmd=<NULL> machine=192.168.1.14 user=test1 path=.
cmd[0]=ssh cmd[1]=-l cmd[2]=test1 cmd[3]=192.168.1.14 cmd[4]=rsync cmd[5]=--server cmd[6]=-vvvvve.LsfxC cmd[7]=. cmd[8]=. 
opening connection using: ssh -l test1 192.168.1.14 rsync --server -vvvvve.LsfxC . .  (9 args)
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=14, file=pipe.c, line=59): entered
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=14, file=pipe.c, line=59): about to call exit(14)
```

Пробовал ставить shell=False, передавать всю команду вместе с параметрами одной строкой - ошибка остается.

Что я могу делать не так ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для использования надо было запустить rsync внутри cygwin shell'a, сделал так:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['sh.exe', '-c',
                            'rsync /cygdrive/e/test test1@192.168.1.14:'],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           env={'CWRSYNCHOME': '/bin/',
                                'PATH': '/bin/'})
```

Так ошибки не возникает (в примере выше опущена авторизация по ssh).